# Different local hostname and CN on domain controller

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-controller, hostname

is there a way to name a server locally "LocalOwnServer" but with a different name on a Domain Controller (ie. "DomainOwnServer")?

so, I would like to exec cmd command *hostname* and to get the result *LocalOwnServer* but if I want to ping it or to connect via RDP I have to use  *DomainOwnServer.mydomain.com*

Comment: Add a static DNS record?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but if I add a static DNS record, I have to create however an object registered as LocalOwnServer, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

DNS entries and hostname aren't actually linked, at least not in a "they must match" kind of way. That's not to say that they *shouldn't* match, but there's no technical reason they *must* match.

It's possible to join a computer to a domain as `localownserver.example.com` (with it's hostname and AD computer object being called 'localownserver', in the 'example.com' domain), but have it respond on the network to `BaconAndEggs.example.com` if you wanted.

It's just matter of creating a DNS alias for `BaconAndEggs.example.com` that points to `localownserver.example.com`.